# Does a visitor to someone already staying in a hotel have to pay the city tax?

Tags: hotels, paris, taxes

Imagine person A is staying in a hotel in Paris for a month. During this month, a friend, person B, comes to visit person A for 10 days and stays in the room A is staying in. The hotel is fully aware of this fact and has even requested the ID of B when he arrived and granted him a key for his ease. Person A is paranoid and explicitely asked if B staying over would change the amount she is being charged for the room. The hotel said that no, that this fact is not relevant for them and that the price stays the same as if B had never come.

When the 10 days are finished B leaves the hotel. The question is, does B have to pay the city tax before leaving, even though the room is reserved for just one person (in this case A)?

Comment: On theory yes. The person stayed in the city. In practice I guess it depends on the hotel but also from the city policy about what is staying, in which circumstances, and who pays what.

Comment: "Person A is paranoid and explicitely asked if B staying over would change the amount she is being charged for the room. The hotel said that no, that this fact is not relevant for them and that the price stays the same as if B had never come." - Is this a real situation? It strikes me that since the tax is per person, not per room then the hotel would tell person A that yes, they will need to pay more to cover the tax for person B. Though I guess they might just not declare it but if they have asked for ID for person B then they have presumably correctly registered things...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless the hotel fails to collect the tax, which they are obliged to collect, B will also have to pay. The Paris tourist tax is subject per person per night with different rates depending on the standard of the accomodation.

Further information about the Paris tourist tax can be found [here](https://en.parisinfo.com/practical-paris/money/tourist-tax).

Comment: I think you've slightly missed part of OP's focus: is city tax therefore collected from a the person who incurred the tax, or from the person who pays the hotel bill? In reality, I've always seen it collected as part of the hotel bill, not as a separate personal fee; but your answer seems to suggest the opposite.

Comment: @Flater Didn't this answer cover that with "unless the hotel fails to collect the tax"?

Comment: @JBentley: It doesn't mention who is _required_ to pay the tax. Let's say both A and B refuse to pay the additional tax. Which person is going to get sued by the hotel? It can't be both of them at the same time. Either the law stipulates whose end responsibility it is to pay (if A => then B can leave the hotel without paying. if B => then A's hotel bill should not increase), or it's at the hotel's discretion (at which point it's important for A to know if it's possible that the hotel ends up charging them for B's tax).

Comment: @Flater: I think the idea is that if person A is refusing to pay the extra that person B will receive a hotel bill for their stay that will include the tax.

Comment: @Chris: That indeed answers the question, I think it'd be a valuable addition to the current answer.

Comment: @Flater: I don't know if that is true though. Personally I would be very surprised if the hotel told person A that their bill wouldn't increase. In practice I would very much expect them to just add it to the bill for Person A.

Comment: @Chris: That was my first reaction too, but when OP said `The hotel is fully aware of this fact and has even requested the ID of B when he arrived and granted him a key for his ease.` I did start to wonder if B was going to go through a separate checkout procedure when handing in their key again.

Comment: @Flater: The fact the OP started with "imagine" suggests to me that this is a purely hypothetical question with conditions that have been made up so I personally am doubting the realism of the original question premise. If the OP says this is an actual situation that they are in or have been then I would accept it but otherwise it feels a bit like "If 1=2 then is X true?".

Comment: @Chris: The question remains valid: hypothetically or not, would an additional guest who has their own checkin also have their own checkout?

Comment: In this case, person A obviously is the holder of the lodging contract with the hotel and therefore responsible towards the hotel for any costs incurring during the stay. The answer is IMHO the same in this case, as if A invited B over to his hotel and B grabbed a can of coke from the minibar.

Comment: The link in the answer says "_All travellers staying in one of the following types of accommodation [...]have a legal obligation to pay_" which suggests it's B's _responsibility_ to pay; later it continues "_This amount must be displayed in the accommodation and must appear on the invoice_" which suggests it will often be _collected_ from/via A (in the same way, presumably, that if a family was staying in a room, the booking would be in one person's name and they would pay the bill for everyone).

Comment: I guess at the end of the day we can conclude that tax is owed for person B and if the hotel has explicitly said they aren't going to collect it from person A then person B must be the one to pay it as this answer says. There is certainly nobody else who would.

Comment: @Chris The hotel has said, that they will not charge more for the *room*. The tourist tax is usually not included in the room price and comes on top of that. Am I missing something else in the question? I can not find anything indicating that the hotel has said that they will not charge A for the tourist tax due to the stay of B.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I would interpret "charge for the room" to include all relevant taxes. But this is again coming to where i dislike this question a lot since it seems very vague and potentially unrealistic about things. eg if I asked a hotel if it would change the cost of the room I wouldn't expect them to just say no - if they were going to charge you the extra tax and they wanted to be precise I would expect them to say "The room charge will be the same but there will be additional tax payable."

Comment: For all of you wondering. Yes this is from a real situation that happened like I describe it. Person B payed the city tax because Person A urged him to request the payment at reception before he left (to a distracted receptionist that was just leaving and wasnt too interested in anything but going home), and person B has always wondered what would have happened had he not requested the payment